# Get changes from feature branch 1 into branch 2 with Git rebase

Tags: git, rebase

I have *two* feature branches `branch-1` and `branch-2`.

I need the changes from feature `branch-1` into feature `branch-2`.

How do I do this with `git rebase`? Is below correct?

```
git checkout branch-1

git rebase branch-2 branch-1
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking? You've put an answer into your question. Does that work, or not?

Answer (score 1):

Would it not be better to merge the changes?

```
git checkout -b branch-1

git merge branch-2
```

If you want to use rebase then according to [this link](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/git-should-i-merge-or-rebase-my-feature-branch?utm_source=Google%20AdWords&aid=5082902844932096&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=kb-dynamic-edpresso&gclid=Cj0KCQiA48j9BRC-ARIsAMQu3WRFwgztpbrNWHaJv6Pc262iKGKkMe3TD4kmvrxufGA2oROUIPpMnecaAkf6EALw_wcB) you could rebase with the command:

```
git checkout -b branch-1

git rebase branch-2
```

Comment: so after your commands above it will put `branch-1` on top of `branch-2`? So all (behind) changes from `branch-1` are now also in `branch-2`?

Comment: After the commands, ```branch-1``` will be put on top of ```branch-2```. But all the changes of ```branch-2``` are now in ```branch-1```. Not the other way around. You can use ```git log --graph``` to see which branch is where.

Comment: ok thanks. But `branch-1` is still in pull-request and after above rebase I can finish branch two and it will be still possible to push `branch-2` and create a pull-request for `branch-2`?

Comment: There are many unknowns, but for the most part I believe that is possible, yes.